# Fixed Length Int Obfuscator. Does anyone know how to do this?

Tags: c#

I am using a generic class to convert an INT to a X base:

```
BaseX basex = new BaseX("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

var a = basex.ToBaseX(1002);
var b = basex.FromBaseX("aghe");
```

And the BaseX class is as follows:

```
public class BaseX {
  private readonly string _digits;

  public BaseX(string digits) {
    _digits = digits;
  }
  public string ToBaseX(int number) {
    var output = "";
    do {
      output = _digits[number % _digits.Length] + output;
      number = number / _digits.Length;
    }
    while (number > 0);
    return output;
  }

  public int FromBaseX(string number) {
    return number.Aggregate(0, (a, c) => a * _digits.Length + _digits.IndexOf(c));
  }
}
```

I am using the lowercase base but I can use any other base.

Is it possible to make the output in the base X always the same length?

I think I should use "Multiplicative Inverse" and some similar process with mapping and encoding but I am not sure how to do this ...

**Could I get some help to create this?**

Basically, my objective is instead of creating random fixed lenght codes to use in promotions or in ID obfuscation just create a fixed length of an INT (The ID on the database).

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to pad the generated value with "zeroes". E.g. if you were using plain numbers and you wanted an ID of length 10 and the ID was 1234 the padded ID would be 0000001234.

The simplest way is to pad the generated value. You can add a new method to the `BaseX` class:

```
public string ToBaseX(int number, int width) {
  var output = ToBaseX(number);
  return output.PadLeft(width, _digits[0]);
}
```

With this method `basex.ToBaseX(1002, 10)` returns

```
aaaaaaabmo
```

and `basex.FromBaseX("aaaaaaabmo")` returns

```
1002
```

In the comments you indicate that the resulting string `aaaaaaabmo` does not seem very random. But then you can use the approach that Eric Lippert describes in the article [A practical use of multiplicative inverses](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/) that you are referring to.

First you need to pick an upper limit to the numbers you want to obfuscate (and this number should fit into a 32 bit integer). Eric Lippert uses 1000000000 (1 billion). You then need to pick a number less than the limit that is coprime with the limit (e.g. they do not share any prime factors). Eric Lippert chooses 387420489 (and explains that any number that ends in 9 will be coprime with a number that is a power of 10). You then need to calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of this number, e.g. a number `inverse-x` that satisfies the following condition:

```
387420489 * inverse-x = 1 (mod 1000000000)
```

You can use the extended Euclidian algorithm for this calculation for instance using [an online calculator](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion-answer.php?n=387420489&p=1000000000). The modular multiplicative inverse is 513180409.

To obfuscate you number you can use this code (to avoid overflow it is important to perform the calculation using 64 bit integers):

```
var value = 1002;
var m = 1000000000L;
var x = 387420489L;
var inverseX = 513180409L;
var encoded = value*x%m;
var decoded = encoded*inverseX%m;
```

For this particular calculation `encoded` is 195329978.

If you want to use the lower case letters to represent the obfuscated number you can use your `BaseX` class to convert the number to base 26. You can compute the maximum letters required to represent any number below 1 billion:

```
Math.Log(1000000000)/Math.Log(26) = 6.36054383137796
```

This means that you need no more than 7 letters to represent your number.

I have combined all this into two simple methods using some constants you can easily customize:

```
static class Obfuscator {

  const Int64 modulo = 1000000000L;

  const Int64 coprime = 280619659L;

  const Int64 inverseCoprime = 687208739L;

  const String digits = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  const Int32 maxDigits = 7; // Math.Log(modulo)/Math.Log(digits.Length) rounded up.

  public static String Obfuscate(Int32 originalValue) {
    if (originalValue >= modulo || originalValue < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    var value = (Int32) (originalValue*coprime%modulo);
    var buffer = new Char[maxDigits];
    var i = maxDigits;
    do {
      buffer[--i] = digits[value%digits.Length];
      value /= digits.Length;
    } while (value > 0);
    while (i > 0)
      buffer[--i] = digits[0];
    return new String(buffer);
  }

  public static Int32 Deobfuscate(String obfuscatedValue) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obfuscatedValue))
      throw new ArgumentException();
    var value = obfuscatedValue
      .Aggregate(0, (a, c) => a*digits.Length + digits.IndexOf(c));
    return (Int32) (value*inverseCoprime%modulo);
  }

}
```

Only detail to be aware of is that `0` is obfuscated into `aaaaaaa`. For any number between 1 and 999999999 (inclusive) you get what looks like a random string of 7 characters.

Comment: Would `String.PadLeft()` be appropriate here?

Comment: @Gusdor: Yes, it is much cleaner so I have changed the code based on your suggestion.

Comment: Excellent. I thought I was missing something important. Arguably, this is a prime candidate for an `ICustomFormatter` implementation on `BaseX`!

Comment: The problem is that the resulting string does not seem very random ... I was looking at this approaches: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=839 and http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/ but I would like to use flexible Base so I can use alphanumeric or any other option ... Any suggestion to this?

Comment: PadLeft is a good approach but how many numbers can you get in there?

Comment: @MDMoura: You can get `base^width` where `base` is the length of your array of digits (in your case 26).